# Splits based on pyparsing

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

so I want to do this (but using pyparsing)

```
Package:numpy11 Package:scipy
will be split into
[["Package:", "numpy11"], ["Package:", "scipy"]]
```

My code so far is

```
package_header = Literal("Package:")
single_package =  Word(printables + " ") + ~Literal("Package:")
full_parser  = OneOrMore( pp.Group( package_header + single_package ) )
```

The current output is this

```
([(['Package:', 'numpy11 Package:scipy'], {})], {})
```

I was hoping for something like this

```
([(['Package:', 'numpy11'], {})], [(['Package:', 'scipy'], {})], {})
```

Essentially the rest of the text matches pp.printables

I am aware that I can use Words but I want to do

```
all printables but not the Literal
```

How do I accomplish this? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need the negative lookahead, ie. this:

```
from pyparsing import *

package_header = Literal("Package:")
single_package =  Word(printables)
full_parser  = OneOrMore( Group( package_header + single_package ) )

print full_parser.parseString("Package:numpy11 Package:scipy")
```

prints:

```
[['Package:', 'numpy11'], ['Package:', 'scipy']]
```

**Update:** to parse packages delimited by `|` you can use the `delimitedList()` function (now you can also have spaces in package names):

```
from pyparsing import *

package_header = Literal("Package:")
package_name = Regex(r'[^|]+')  # | is a printable, so create a regex that excludes it.
package = Group(package_header + package_name) 
full_parser = delimitedList(package, delim="|" )

print full_parser.parseString("Package:numpy11 foo|Package:scipy")
```

prints:

```
[['Package:', 'numpy11 foo'], ['Package:', 'scipy']]
```

Comment: What if I do not have the space and have a pipe like this: "Package:numpy11|Package:scipy" ? I am pretty new to pyparsing. Thanks.

Comment: @user2707389 I've updated my answer (`delimitedList(..)` is useful in all situations where the delimiter should only be between items).

Comment: `Regex(r'[^|]+')` can also be written as `Word(printables, excludeChars='|')`